# add a pair into an unorderedmap with minimum copies

Tags: c++

I have an unordered map: unordered_map<int, std::pair<Data, int>> m_map. I want to define a function that emplaces a copy of Data object. Ideally create one Data obejct using copy construcor. here are the things I tried, but the best I could do is copy constructor and move constructor, so 2 copies. can this be improves?

```
#include  <iostream>
#include  <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

struct Data 
{
    Data() { cout <<"ctor"<<endl;}
    Data(const Data &) { cout <<"cctor"<<endl;}
    Data(const Data &&) { cout <<"mtor"<<endl;}
    
    const Data& operator=(const Data &) { cout <<"op="<<endl; return *this;}
};

unordered_map<int, std::pair<Data, int>> m_map;

void add(Data& data)
{
//  m_map.emplace(22, {data, 4}); // does not compile
//  m_map.emplace(22, data, 4); // does not compile
    m_map.emplace(22, std::pair(data,4)); // calls cctor and movector
    m_map.insert({22, {data,4}}); // calls cctor,cctor, and movector

}

int main()
{
    Data data;
    
    add(data);
}
```

Comment: Did you try `std::pair(std::move(data),4)`?

Comment: If you'd use ``std::move(data)`` instead of ``data`` where you inset the object into the map (since data is a lvalue reference) then you'd probably avoid at least one copy constructor. Also, if your move constructor is *not* ``noexcept`` then the standard library may decide to call the copy constructor instead in certain places.

Comment: Also `reference_wrapper` is an option, so `std::pair{std::ref{data}, 4}`, perhaps... This should delay the copy as much as possible.

Comment: You may want to use different keys, otherwise your feedback may be influenced whether it is an insert or an update.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/fb78hrazd

Answer (score 4):

`std::unordered_map::emplace` (like `std::map::emplace`) allows you to pass `std::piecewise_construct` to construct both the key and value in-place, from their respective constructor parameters.

```
m_map.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
              std::forward_as_tuple(22),      // Key, constructed in place
              std::forward_as_tuple(data,4)); // Value, constructed in place
```

This will avoid the extra constructor call in your best attempt.

[Compiler Explorer example of this code compiling](https://godbolt.org/z/vhY9Pe9TT)

Comment: this does not compile...

Comment: @DuduArbel I have added a link, showing this code compiling and running.

Comment: my mistake. this is wonderfull

Comment: May also point out that this can be [turtles all the way down](https://godbolt.org/z/nesGK8nTY). If one would like to forward other (if any) arguments directly to the pair wrapping `Data`, the second tuple can also contain `std::forward_as_tuple(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(/*args for data*/), std::forward_as_tuple(4))`

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/fb78hrazd